# linq to sql stored procedure call fails

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have recursive stored procedure on SQL Server. I'm using Linq-to-SQL generated classes, and drag & drop procedure to this class.

Other procedures are working fine, but this procedures fails with exception:

> "System.Void" not allowed return
>   type. invalid operation exception

Stored procedure:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[delListEnterprise]
@pin_list_enterprise_id numeric(38,0), 
@cCriteria varchar(250) = null,
@iLevel int = 0
AS
begin
set nocount on
declare
    @cSQL varchar(255),
    @cChildCriteria varchar(255),
    @iLevelNew int
IF @iLevel = 0
    BEGIN
        set @cCriteria='parent_list_enterprise_id='+cast(@pin_list_enterprise_id as varchar(30));
        delete from list_enterprise where list_enterprise_id=@pin_list_enterprise_id;
        Create Table #tblCascadeDelete (CallLevel int NOT NULL, PKValue int NOT NULL)
    END
SET @cSQL = 'INSERT INTO #tblCascadeDelete ( CallLevel, PKValue ) SELECT ' + Convert(varchar(3), @iLevel) + ' As CallLevel, list_enterprise_id As PKValue FROM list_enterprise WHERE ' + @cCriteria
EXEC (@cSQL)
IF @@RowCount > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @cChildCriteria = '[parent_list_enterprise_id] IN (SELECT [PKValue] FROM #tblCascadeDelete Where [CallLevel] = ' + Convert(varchar(3), @iLevel) + ')'
        SET @iLevelNew = @iLevel + 1
        EXEC delListEnterprise null,@cChildCriteria, @iLevelNew
    END
SET @cSQL = 'DELETE FROM list_enterprise WHERE ' + @cCriteria
EXEC (@cSQL)
IF @iLevel = 0
    BEGIN
        Drop Table #tblCascadeDelete
    END
ELSE
    DELETE FROM #tblCascadeDelete WHERE CallLevel = @iLevel
end
```

It works, if I run it in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a return/output parameter to the stored proc. I suspect this is a Linq2SQL limitation (or no-one thought of it).